# Compile and run program without main() in C

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, program-entry-point, gcc-warning

I'm trying to compile and run following program without `main()` function in `C`. I have compiled my program using the following command.

```
gcc -nostartfiles nomain.c
```

And compiler gives warning

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400340
```

Ok, No problem. then, I have run executable file(a.out), both `printf` statements print successfully, and then get **segmentation fault**.

So, my question is, **Why segmentation fault after successfully execute print statements?**

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void nomain()
{
        printf("Hello World...\n");
        printf("Successfully run without main...\n");
}
```

**output:**

```
Hello World...
Successfully run without main...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Note:**

Here, `-nostartfiles` gcc flag prevents the compiler from using standard startup files when linking

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all. Frankly, I consider this treatment by the linker to be erroneous (or at least a Bad Thing): there was no entry point, so the linker just hallucinated it from whatever function was handy. Blech.

Comment: @imallett, at least the linker was kind enough to draw attention to it with a warning and to explain what fallback action it was taking!  You're right that this might be better as an error rather than just a warning, though.

Comment: Why would you use no main?

Comment: @PieterB - Not overly relevant to a discussion about unices, but the entry point for Windows programs isn't necessarily `main`, but `WinMain` or `wWinMain`.

Comment: @StoryTeller actually in both Windows and Linux you can set arbitrary entry point: for Linux's `ld` it would be `-e` option, for Windows' MSVC linker it'd be `/ENTRY` option.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Let's have a look at the generated [assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/0g5RA9) of your program:

```
.LC0:
        .string "Hello World..."
.LC1:
        .string "Successfully run without main..."
nomain:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        call    puts
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Note the `ret` statement. Your program's entry point is determined to be `nomain`, all is fine with that. But once the function returns, it attempts to jump into an address on the call stack... that isn't populated. That's an illegal access and a segmentation fault follows.

A quick solution would be to call `exit()` at the end of your program (and assuming C11 we might as well mark the function as `_Noreturn`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

_Noreturn void nomain(void)
{
    printf("Hello World...\n");
    printf("Successfully run without main...\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

In fact, now your function behaves pretty much like a regular `main` function, since after returning from `main`, the `exit` function is called with `main`'s return value.

Comment: I think there are some architecture/OS combinations where you can just "return" out of a program; MS-DOS .COM executables? Anyway, we're deep into implementation-specific behaviour.

Comment: @pjc50 - We are indeed. Although the path in the OP suggested a Unix variant. That coupled with the popularity of certain architectures and instruction sets was the only reason I felt comfortable to present generated assembly in the answer.

Comment: Just an observation. `-nostartfiles` can also render the C library unusable. Without the _C_ startup executed subsequent calls to the _C_ library functions may fail unexpectedly. On Linux if you were to compile with `-nostartupfiles` and `-static` you may discover the program will fault. There are _C_ libraries like MUSL that don't require up front initialization that are designed to work in this environment.

Answer (score 22):

In C, when functions/subroutines are called the stack is populated as (in the order):

1. The arguments,
2. Return address,
3. Local variables, --> **top of the stack**

main() being the start point, ELF structures the program in such a way that whatever instructions comes first would get pushed first, in this case printfs are.

Now, program is sort of truncated without return-address OR `__end__` and infact it assumes that whatever is there on the stack at that(`__end__`) location is the return-address, but unfortunately its not and hence it crashes.

Comment: Is the order of stack data defined by the C standard? I thought it was up to the system architecture

Comment: Thats why i mentioned ELF(executable and linkable file format), this is generated by cross-compiling for a specific ARCH type on the required OS.

Comment: To be picky, you can use the ELF format even on systems with no stack. One example of such a system is [Freescale RS08](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freescale_RS08) with the Codewarrior compiler, which generates ELF linker files.